# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, static-methods, onclicklistener

I am receiving an error on me method to allow a class access to my DB. the error is occurring at .getReadableDatabase(). The error received is below. not sure how to fix this error.

```
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getReadableDatabase() from the type SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Method:

```
 public static boolean vaidateUser(String username, String password) {
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_CREDENTIALS + " WHERE "
                        + COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + "='" + username +"'AND "+COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD+"='"+password+"'" ,  null);
       if (c.getCount()>0)
          return true;
          return false;
```

used to call this method:

```
  lsLogin.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //check login
                    String username = lsUsername.getText().toString();
                    String password = lsPassword.getText().toString();
                    try{
                        if(LoginDB.vaidateUser(username,password)) {
                            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), menu.class);
                            startActivity(goToNextActivity);

                                Toast.makeText(LoginScrExample.this,"Login Sucessful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(LoginScrExample.this,"Invalid Username/Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you need an instance of an object to call this method as it is not `static`

Do something like: `Cursor c = new YourObject().getReadableDatabase()...`

Or make the called method also `static`

Answer (score 3):

The error is being thrown because you are calling a non static method:

```
getReadableDatabase();
```

Any method you call in a static method must also be static.

To fix it, either remove the static from the static method, or add static to all the used methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is a method of [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29).

So do this instead:

```
Cursor c = new SQLiteOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase()..
```

or

```
SQLiteOpenHelper soh = new SQLiteOpenHelper();
Cursor c = soh().getReadableDatabase()..
```